# Retrieving data from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having difficulty in retrieving data from JSON. When I click the button, it will fire call function and call function will call `json.jsp` file to retrieve data from array. Now I can't retrieve data. Here is my JavaScript file;

```
var callback;
function call(uid, pw) {
    callback = true;
    $.getJSON("json.jsp" + "?uid=" + uid + "&rdm=" + Math.random(), function (data) {
        $.each(data.menulist, function (key, val) {
            $("#cont").append("<div>" + val + "</div>");
        });
        callback = false;
    });
}
```

And the following is my jsp file;

```
String uid=request.getParameter("uid")==null?"xxx":request.getParameter("uid");

if (uid.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){  
  {"menulist":[{"menu":"menu1"},{"menu":"menu2"},{"menu":"menu3"}]}   
} else if (uid.equalsIgnoreCase("user")){   
   {"menulist":[{"menu":"menu1"},{"menu":"menu2"}]}
} else {   
  {"menu":"Menu"}
}
```

Comment: Any errors in logs  ? Did you check the request in the network console ?

Comment: yes, I've checked with network.

Comment: And ? Does the request reaches the server ? If so, what's the response like ?

Comment: There's no response.I've checked the other function, it worked. So there's no problem with network.

Comment: Did you check server's logs ? Could you please provide a trace of the request and of the reponse ?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to trace server logs.

Comment: Can't help you much more, you need to get logs on server side (or use debug mode). You can also use breakpoints in the js console.

Comment: ok I will try my own. anyway thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got it like this;

`$("#cont").append("<div>" + data.menulist[i].menu + "</div>");`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSP code doesn't look right. You should enclose the JSP scriptlet with <% %> as followed:

```
<%String uid=request.getParameter("uid")==null?"xxx":request.getParameter("uid");

if (uid.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){  %>
    {"menulist":[{"menu":"menu1"},{"menu":"menu2"},{"menu":"menu3"}]}   
<%} else if (uid.equalsIgnoreCase("user")){   %>
    {"menulist":[{"menu":"menu1"},{"menu":"menu2"}]}
<%} else {   %>
    {"menu":"Menu"}
<%}%>
```

Have you try accessing the URL directly and check if the JSP output the right JSON content.

```
http://localhost:8080/yourapp/json.jsp?uid=admin&rdm=1
```

Comment: yeah I know. I removed it to post here.